# How can I compress .mov files to fit on DVD-Rs on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, software-rec, compression, dvd-burning

I'm running Mac OS X 10.6 and have a few large .mov files (around 20-30GB each) that I would like to burn onto separate data DVD-Rs. The resolution of the videos is 960x540 and the duration ranges from about 2h13m to 2h45m.

I've never compressed and burned video files before so I'm looking for recommendations for a program (preferably free) that can help me do this easily. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be to try `ffmpeg`, probably the most powerful en/decoder library available. Normally, you'd have to compile it on OS X yourself, but there's a slightly older prebuilt version called [**`ffmpegX`**](http://www.ffmpegx.com/), which bundles the `ffmpeg` libraries into a GUI application, which is of course free.

- Download that (here's the [direct download link](ftp://ftp2.ffmpegx.com/ffmpegx/ffmpegX.dmg)) and install it.
- After opening it for the first time, it asks you to install additional libraries. You can do that, but you don't *need* to.
- Drop the MOV file into the field where it says "Drop here"
- Choose an appropriate output codec. In order to retain the best quality, go for `h.264 x264`. Also change the output file name to `.mp4`.

[image]

- Now go to the second tab ("Video") and enter your target file size or select 1 DVD (4GB). **Then** click "Rate" to calculate the bit rate necessary for fitting the newly encoded file to the medium you specified before. <sub>Note that my numbers are off, because I only used a 0:30 min test file</sub>

[image]

- Then hit "Encode"

---

A few remarks:

- I can't promise it works, but `ffmpeg` should be able to handle everything. Another note: Handbrake also uses `libavcodec` which is bundled into `ffmpeg`, so it should have been able to decode your MOV files as well.
- It might be that your MOV files are encoded with some codec that `ffmpeg` will not understand, in that case we might have to dig deeper.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you need [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/downloads.php), which requires [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-macosx.html) (at least if you want full functionality out of it; you might only need it to do DVD ripping, but it's worth having anyway).

You can set a target size for the video - under "quality" in the video section.

Comment: Ah PERFECT! I'll give this a go and update you on how it went. Thanks!

Comment: Ok so I installed Handbrake and VLC. However when I import the .mov file in Handbrake it says "Scanning title 1 of 1" for a few minutes before it says "No Valid Source Found". The .mov file is saved on an external drive connected through firewire if it makes a difference. I checked the "Activity Window" and it has several entries of "scan: could not get a decoded picture" after "scan: decoding previews for title 1"

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure if Handbrake supports the encoding of your MOV file (since MOV is a container, and not an actual file format...). Sorry about that. Another fairly popular program seems to be Squared5 - never used it, but it might be worth a go! http://www.squared5.com/

Comment: @tvguide1234 Maybe try to install [Perian](http://perian.org/), doesn't hurt. Handbrake *should* be able to do what you want.

Comment: @Joseph I tried squared5 and it works to convert the files but I don't see any option to set the target file size. Since the files are 20-30GB and take a while to encode, I can't do this through trial and error.

Comment: @slhck I feel like Handbrake is exactly what I need but it won't read the file. Is there something special besides installation that I need to do in order to get VLC and Handbrake to work together?